# Pickling tuple of ndarrays which share memory consumes double space

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pickle

```py
import numpy as np
import pickle

a = np.random.rand(4000)
b = a.T

assert np.shares_memory(a, b)

tup = (a, b)
s = pickle.dumps(tup)
print(len(s)) # 64187

s1 = pickle.dumps(a)
print(len(s1)) # 32151
```

Since `a` and `b` share the same memory, when pickling them, the result should be close to the result of pickling one of them.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: pickle for arrays uses `np.save` to write each one.  The save format has a header with shape, dtype info, and copy of its data-buffer.  That's a copy, not a link to buffer of its base.  And on load it's a new array. The `view/base` of the original arrays is not preserved during a file write and reload.

Comment: Since `a` is a 1d array, `b` is the same - but it is a `view`, a new array that use's `a` data.  Or in other words `b.base` is `a`.  While we can check for properties like that `np.save(filename, b)` does not.  It writes a copy of `b's` data to the file, same as if `b` owned it.  And pickling `(a,b)` doesn't change how `b` is written.  The `tuple` doesn't "know" anything about numpy arrays; it has has pointers to objects in memory..  Similarly on load/unpickle there's no attempt to recreate `b` as a transpose of `a`.  It's just another array.